# Problem on Unity 2020 and Firebase (Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode')

Tags: c#, android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I upgrade my app for Android on Unity 2019.12 to 2020.1. With Unity 2019, Firebase work fine. But with Unity 2020, i have 2 errors. I not use IOS, just Android. How to resolve this ?
Thanks.

```
Assembly 'Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Assembly 'Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/Google.IOSResolver_v1.2.135.0.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into this issue by having built the project with iOS Build Support enabled, and then loading the project with a new version of Unity (2020), with iOS Build Support disabled.

Adding iOS build support to the install solved the missing dependency issues.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Your solution solves the problem. Firebase Messaging work fine on Unity 2020. But just Push Notification doesn't work on Unity 2020. I contacted Firebase team and they answered me Unity 2020 is broken with firebase. ( no receive token for push notification)

Comment: Worked for me also. Not sure why I didnt try that first lol. It so obvious now.

Comment: How do you disable the iOS Build Support? Is it on the firebase side or the unity side?

Answer (score 3):

This is just the runtime error for the android app, we still can build and run the application. Do not worry about the error and no need to install iOS build support.

Answer (score 1):

No need to install iOS Build support, just uncheck the "Validate References" checkbox in the plugin inspector.